# Installing OpenCV for Python in Ubuntu 12.04. No module present in dist-packages or site-packages?

Tags: linux, opencv, python-3.x, installation, python-3.2

Following the steps given [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20%3a%20Debian), i have completed the installation process, however Python (IDLE) is giving me an ImportError. For which the guide suggests :

> Python may return to you an error like "`No module named cv`" The trouble is that the python module is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages`. But, on Debian and on Ubuntu, Python only looks in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`
>
> You can fix it using three ways (Use only one of those, the first is the best):
>
> 1. move the `cv.so` file from the `site-packages` to the `dist-packages`:
>
>    `sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cv.so /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cv.so`

However, both the site-packages as well as dist-packages, for both 2.7 and 3.2 are empty.

What went wrong and how do i solve it ?

Comment: Try `>>> import cv2`. New Opencv-python is cv2,not cv.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK No, doesnt work.

Comment: try this : http://karytech.blogspot.in/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: Every time i try to install, it does not give any warnings or errors but when i try to find the libraries in `/usr/local/lib` there is nothing there, other than python-2.7 and python-3.2 ! >:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing all the packages and dependencies again using the Software Center. OpenCV Python bindings are available for OpenCV 2.3 and Python 2.7 directly from the software center which I used the second time.

OpenCv python bindings for 3.2 are not available for 12.04. They are being developed for Raring (Ubuntu 13.04) only. Hence, the solution is to use either backports, or to use OpenCv on Python 2.7

Backports also have a problem as they are available only for 32 bit OS systems and not 64 bit.

So, the only safe and stable way to run OpenCV Python on Ubuntu seems to be using OpenCV 2.3 on Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

I also get the empty dist-packages folder with OpenCV2.4.4 and Ubuntu 12.04. It turns out that I need to install `python-dev` and `python-numpy` in order to make the cv.so compiled into the dist-packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy
```

After that, using `cmake` to build OpenCV again and everything will be fine

**UPDATE**
it depends on your system pretty much.

- On my Lion (10.8), I have java installed, and openCV complaints about cannot build the unit test and stop at 92%. It turned out that I have to manually create the build folder and put the junit jar into the lib folder in order to let opencv compile all the test case. After that, everything is ok
- On my ubuntu (12.04, fresh installation with build-essential and all packages are up-to-date), eveything is compiled fine, except that "No module named cv" and there is not cv.so in the `dist-packages` and `site-packages`. Searching around and then finally, it turned out that I have to have python-dev and python-numpy

Comment: Are the supporting packages for 2.4 not giving you issues on installation because of the Raring packages ? I got a lot of errors/problems each of which I had to manually override.